# How to set android application custom theme with custom action bar background?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-theme, android-styles

I want to set a custom theme to my android application, but unable to do so.  Following is my xml snippet :

res/values/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In manifest I've changed the android:theme property to :
   android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"

But still, its not working for me. The theme am getting is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by modifying style.xml :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="CustomAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's because, when you're using `AppCompat` you define attributes without `android:` prefix ie. `android:background`, `android:colorPrimary`. Read this page carefully, if you want to keep your app backward compatible: [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create res/values/style.xml or make these changes in res/values/style.xml

themes.xml not work in android project.

And set your custom theme in your manifest in

```
<application ...
android:theme="@style/Your_Custom_Theme_Name"
>
 ...
</application>
```

Comment: but this way I found on developer.android.com.  Plus, the one you mentioned is not working

Comment: Yes. I am extending with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add your `CustomActionBarTheme` theme in `res/values/style.xml` and it will work.

Comment: but this way I found on developer.android.com.  Plus, the one you mentioned is not working